# What do I need to configure if PHP Pear is working from the command line but not my browser?

Tags: php, pear

My script is dying at

```
require_once "Mail.php"
```

I have configured php.ini correctly.  It runs from the command line but the exact same script dies in my browser.  I'm guessing it's something simple but I can't quite work out what. Running Centos 5

Edit:

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/local/PEAR/')

which is strange

under /usr/share/pear

I have

-rw-r--r--  1 root root  8934 Jul 20  2007 Mail.php

Comment: Do you have any logs available? In your browser the script has been executed with different access rights. Usually it's path-issue or access rights. We are able to help you better if you can provide some logs here.

Comment: I'm not very good at sysadmin.  Which logs should I be looking at?

Comment: Is the PHP your using at the Cmd Line the same PHP that is set to run from Apache? Remember that they are two separate things PHP and Apache.

Comment: What kind of error you get in the browser ?
You should check the include_path if it's pointing at PEAR files.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has two different .ini files, one for the server module and one for the cli. They must have the same configuration options. Maybe you are missing the pear path in the server module!

Comment: I didn't realize this. Pardon the naiveté but where do I find the configuration file for the server module?

Comment: It depends of which OS do you use. For ubuntu/linux they are under /etc/php5, apache2 for the server module, anche cli for the command line. For windows , you have to look where php is installed!

Comment: just call PHP's `phpinfo()` function in the browser, and it will display the location of php.ini file that is being used by Apache.